# Converting SQL query to Lambda

Tags: sql, join, lambda, where-clause

Can anyone help me translate the below sql to lambda?

```
SELECT a.assembly_name,
    a.financial_year,
    a.total_expenditure,
    SUM(b.ac_bill_amount) AS TOTAL_AC_BILL
    FROM fund_allotment AS a INNER JOIN mla_ac_bill AS b
    ON a.assembly_name = b.assembly_name and a.financial_year = b.financial_year
    GROUP BY a.assembly_name,a.financial_year,a.total_expenditure
```

Comment: [c#] would have been a great tag here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = fundAllotment
    .Join(mlaAcBill,
        a => new { a.AssemblyName, a.FinancialYear },
        b => new { b.AssemblyName, b.FinancialYear },
        (a, b) => new
        {
            a.AssemblyName,
            a.FinancialYear,
            a.TotalExpenditure,
            b.AC_Bill_Amount
        })
    .GroupBy(x => new
    {
        x.AssemblyName,
        x.FinancialYear,
        x.TotalExpenditure
    })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key.AssemblyName,
        g.Key.FinancialYear,
        g.Key.TotalExpenditure,
        TotalACBill = g.Sum(x => x.AC_Bill_Amount)
    });
```

Comment: @Nishanttirkey it's a bad response. The very fact you're trying to use LINQ as if it was SQL is a misuse of LINQ and EF Core.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want this:

```
from fa in fund_allotment
join mab in mla_ac_bill
    on new { fa.assembly_name, fa.financial_year }
    equals new { mab.assembly_name, mab.financial_year }
group mab.ac_bill_amount
    by new { fa.assembly_name, fa.financial_year, fa.total_expenditure }
    into g
select new
{
    g.Key.assembly_name,
    g.Key.financial_year,
    g.Key.total_expenditure,
    TOTAL_AC_BILL = g.Sum()
};
```